# cypress - This element is not visible

Tags: cypress

i want to trigger a button after 150 seconds so i written a logic like this.

```
   ///<reference types="cypress"/>
describe("home test",function (){
    it('home',function (){
        cy.visit('http://localhost/SNL.Services.Application.Common.Service/v1/client?ccaTopNav=1&auth=inherit#news/home');
        cy.get('.header-button > .btn-default',{timeout:180000}).click({force: true});

        cy.intercept('POST', 'https://platform.midevcld.spglobal.com/apisvcs/logging-service/v1/AI/LogClientTelemetry?clientdate=1650881902895', {
            statusCode: 204
          }).as('lastXhr')

          cy.wait('@lastXhr')
          cy.contains('.header-button', 'REMIND ME LATER')
        
    })
})
```

my actual scenario: when i opened the localhost its takes time(65s) to open the  popup so that i added a functionality to click the button after 150 seconds.
in the (65 seconds) meantime it making some api call that is the delay for the 55s.

but after 55 th second it takes 5-10s to open the popup. that's where my Remind me button is located. but when the 55seconds completed its showing the few html elements(after that take 10 sec to show popup) in that it immedietly checking the selector so that my button click is not working as expected.

[image]

can anyone guide me how to make the click event on my scenario.

Comment: You say it 'takes time' does that mean the app performance takes that long or is there a timer set for the popup/elements to appear?

Comment: in local server it'll take time but in dev/uat/prod it'll execute in 4 seconds. the problem i'm facing in local server testing. the popup will enable based on api response.

Comment: Please do not use cypress tags that are not applicable to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the order, intercept should always go at the top.

```js
cy.intercept('POST', 'https://platform.midevcld.spglobal.com/apisvcs/logging-service/v1/AI/LogClientTelemetry?clientdate=1650881902895', 
  {statusCode: 204}
).as('lastXhr')

cy.visit('http://localhost/SNL.Services.Application.Common.Service/v1/client?ccaTopNav=1&auth=inherit#news/home');
cy.get('.header-button > .btn-default',{timeout:180000}).click({force: true});

cy.wait('@lastXhr')
cy.contains('.header-button', 'REMIND ME LATER')
```